# Opening .exe from java Codes

Tags: java

Here is my code I wanted to open  ODBC bridge through Java

Code:

```
   try{
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process p = null;
                try{
                    String s = "C://windows/System32/odbcad32.exe";
                    p=r.exec(s);
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

and here is the problem  which I am facing

```
Cannot run program "C://windows/System32/odbcad32.exe": CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to be at a higher user privilege than you're at right now.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/ConnecttoAccessDatabaseusingJDBCODBCbridge.htm

Comment: Execute the code as an administrator.

Comment: Do you want to stablish a connection JDBC-ODBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to edit the connections in odbcad32? If so I can't help you there, I have in my own projects caught the SQLException and used the Desktop class to open obdcad32 like:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\odbcad32.exe"));
```

That will open obdcad32 on 64bit systems if connecting to an access database. If your able to connect with 64 bit drivers then you can discard the SysWOW64 folder and replace it with System32 (or if using a 32 bit system.

Comment: Thank you guys 
Especially  Cumberland Engineer   Your Code Works Perfectly I also Have in my own project , Thanks again .